# Ubuntu 20.04 keyboard and mouse rebooting

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I'm facing an odd problem here.
With a KVM switch I control both my working laptop (windows 10) and my personal desktop (ubuntu 20.04), the problem is the keyboard and mouse switched to windows works fine but on ubuntu they keep getting rebooted every 5 seconds as if I disconected them and conected again.
I plugged them on my desktop without the KVM switch and worked fine, so it couldnt be motherboard ports or ubuntu handling, but on the other hand the switch works fine on windows.
I’m a little lost here, does anyone have any guesses?

Comment: Hello. Just because the switch works on windows does not mean that it does not have an issue. Did you try re wiring so that the 2 computers are using different ports on the switch? Ubuntu using the inputs that Windows was using.

Comment: I fixed the issue was an autosuspend grub flag: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-kernel-3-7-10-or-above